# ¿Como puedo hacer que un switch me compare un for in?

Tags: javascript

para ser un poco más especifico, quiero comparar 6 colores con casos en switch, usando un indice como arreglo en for para recorrer los elementos, pero no se bien como seria una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Es necesario que muestres lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunas cosas que no me quedan muy en claro con respecto a lo que preguntas:
¿Necesitas que el switch este dentro de tu "for in"?
¿Que propiedad del objeto (índice) necesitas usar, la llave o el valor?
Quizá algún ejemplo sobre lo que necesitas lograr.

De cualquier manera en base a lo que dices yo te podría proponer esta solución:

```
const doSomeStuff = (color) => {
    let resp = ''; 
    switch(color){
        case 'rojo':   resp = 'fuego'; break;
        case 'verde':  resp = 'planta'; break;
        case 'morado': resp = 'veneno'; break;
        default: resp = 'nothing';     
    }
    return resp;
}
fruitObj = { manzana:'rojo', naranja:'naranja', uva:'morado', limon:'verde' }
respArr = Object.values(fruitObj).map( color => doSomeStuff(color) );
```

1. Declaras una función que le pasaras como parámetro el valor a comparar y que tendrá dentro el switch
2. Declaras tu Objeto.
3. Obtienes el valor de cada propiedad de tu objeto y al mismo tiempo las mapeas.
4. En cada iteración de tu arreglo de valores se la pasas a tu función con el switch.
5. Obtienes el arreglo con los resultados de cada valor.